# SQL Query compare data in different rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I had this question at a job interview yesterday and although it seemed pretty straight fwd I couldn't figure it out and it's kept me awake all night thinking about it.

The system records data about a scrabble league there is a members table, a games table and a joining member_games table.

```
members: member_id, name : pk(member_id)
member_games: game_id, member_id, score : pk(game_id, member_id)
games: game_id, location, date : pk(game_id)

members
1, mick
2, keith
3, charlie

member_games
1, 1, 50
1, 2, 60
2, 1, 45
2, 3, 105
3, 1, 30
3, 3, 120

game
1, london, 2012-12-01
2, richmond, 2012-12-02
3, leeds, 2012-12-03
```

How do you formulate an SQL query to find out the number of wins for the `member_id` = 1?

Comment: sorry, mysql. Will using max() count draws as wins?

Comment: Yes it will count draws as ties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will give you the number of wins for member_id 1.

```
select count(*) as number_of_wins
    from member_games as mg1
    where member_id = 1
    and not exists (select 1
        from member_games as mg2
        where mg2.game_id = mg1.game_id
        and mg2.member_id <> mg1.member_id
        and mg2.score >= mg1.score);
```

The following query will give you the list of members with their respective number of wins.

```
select m.*,
    (select count(*) from member_games as mg1
        where member_id = m.member_id
        and not exists (select 1
            from member_games as mg2
            where mg2.game_id = mg1.game_id
            and mg2.member_id <> mg1.member_id
            and mg2.score >= mg1.score)
    ) as number_of_wins
    from members as m;
```

These queries do not consider ties for first place as wins.

I created a [MySQL SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c96a2/25) and a [SQL Server SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c96a2/6).

Comment: cool, the solutions using max() count draws as wins, this solution doesn't

Comment: @jx12345:  Actually, my original answer did treat draws (ties) as wins, but now that I know you don't want to treat them as wins, I changed `>` to `>=` and now it doesn't treat them as wins.

Answer (score 4):

Query to find the number of wins for `member_id = 1`,

```
SELECT COUNT(1) "No. of Wins"
  FROM (SELECT game_id, member_id, score
          FROM member_games b
         WHERE score =
               (SELECT max(score) from member_games WHERE game_id = b.game_id)) A
 WHERE member_id = 1;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72632/11)

Comment: Oh so you answered because it is related to Sports. ;)

Comment: @hims056 lol. That's the reputation I have eh? :P Good to see you here though ':)`

Answer (score 2):

The key is to group the member_games first and get the highest score and then join that back to the member_games table to get the member_id.

The fact is that you need a left join to see that Member_id won 0 games.

```
SELECT
    member_games.member_id
    ,COUNT(BestScore.game_id)
FROM member_games
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT game_id, MAX(score) AS HighestScore FROM member_games GROUP BY Game_ID
    ) BestScore ON member_games.Score = BestScore.HighestScore
AND member_games.game_id = BestScore.game_id
WHERE member_games.member_id = 1
GROUP BY member_games.member_id;
```

Here it is on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c96a2/21/0) as MySQL

This solution counts ties as wins, but it should work on any SQL server.  The Rank function is available in Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and higher.

For completeness, Here's a more complex query that doesn't count ties as wins:

```
SELECT
    member_games.member_id
    ,COUNT(BestScore.game_id)
FROM member_games
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT member_games.game_id, HighestScore
    FROM member_games
    LEFT JOIN
        (
          SELECT game_id, MAX(score) AS HighestScore FROM member_games GROUP BY Game_ID
        ) BestScore ON member_games.Score = BestScore.HighestScore
        AND member_games.game_id = BestScore.game_id
        GROUP BY game_id, HighestScore
        HAVING count(1) = 1
    ) BestScore ON member_games.Score = BestScore.HighestScore
WHERE member_games.member_id = 1
GROUP BY member_games.member_id;
```

Ties as losses on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8c59/8/0) as MySQL

Comment: thanks, is there any way to take draws into account, i think with this they count as wins

Comment: Good call.  I just edited it to count ties as losses.  GMM beat me to it and with fewer characters.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it (SQL Server syntax)

```
SELECT member_id
      ,COUNT(*) Wins
FROM   (
       SELECT member_id
             ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Game_Id ORDER BY score DESC) Position
       FROM  member_games
       ) Positions
WHERE Position=1
      AND
      member_id=1
GROUP BY member_id
```

The `RANK()` allows for the possibility of ties which are possible (if unlikely) in Scrabble. `ROW_NUMBER()` may offer a small performance enhancement in games where a tie is not possible.

This method can be easily expanded to show all placings as

```
SELECT member_id
      ,Position
      ,COUNT(*) Games
FROM   (
       SELECT member_id
             ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Game_Id ORDER BY score DESC) Position
       FROM  member_games
       ) Positions
WHERE member_id=1
GROUP BY member_id
        ,Position
```

See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c96a2/7) SQL Fiddle